# How to click the hyperlink via Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, bots

I want to perform this :

1)Go to http://www.bbc.co.uk/search?q= (done)

2) Search "apple" (done)

3) Click submit (done)

4) Click the first result or all results ( this I do it in hard code ,if any method can choose the first result ,it is appreciated)  (now working)

---

I have finished first 3 steps .However, for the step 4 , I don't know how to do it .As the hyperlink doesn't consist of a `ID`

```
 <h1 itemprop="headline"><a href="http://www.bbc.co.uk/music/artists/12eec8cf-cd35-410d-91e7-31343029ac39">Apple</a></h1>
                        <p class="summary short">&hellip;The BBC artist page for <em>Apple</em>. Find the best clips, programmes, news and interviews&hellip;</p>
                        <p class="summary medium">&hellip;The BBC artist page for <em>Apple</em>. Find the best clips, programmes, news and interviews.&hellip;</p>
```

whole code:

```
WebDriver driver;
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Users\\Downloads\\geckodriver-v0.10.0-win64\\wires.exe");
driver =new FirefoxDriver();


driver.get("http://www.bbc.co.uk/search?q=");
driver.findElement(By.id("orb-search-q")).sendKeys("apple");//enter apple
driver.findElement(By.id("orb-search-button")).click(); //click submit button
```

Answer (score -1):

Any of the following should work for you but the findElements method should serve your purpose better

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Apple")) :Assuming there is only one apple, either ways it will click the first "Apple" link
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@href, "music/artists")

or driver.findElements(By.linkText("Apple")).get(0) 
// or whatever the index of the first link will be
driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a[contains(@href, "music/artists")).get(0)
```

Comment: In the generic case, what if none of the links is exactly the search term, e.g. "Apple"? This won't work.

Comment: Then they can use the By.partialLinkText method. The concept still remains the same.

Comment: Even better if a parameterized search string is used as the text

Comment: My point is that OP asked to click the first link. Your answer may work on this example but it won't if you change the search text.

Comment: Ofcourse and the answer had an alternate solution for that problem. The linkText solution would have been appropriate in a scenario where  the first link with the search string needs to be clicked.

Comment: The `linkText()` solution only works when you know the text of the link. You won't in the general case.

Answer (score -1):

I approach tasks like these with an attempt to find a general solution so that it can be applied to (hopefully) *any* situation/query. In order to do that, we need to look at the HTML of the results page and find the container for the search results so we can narrow down individual search results and find the link for each result. Then we can pick any result we want based on some criteria and then follow that link, etc.

If you look at the HTML of the result page, the search results are all contained in this element.

```
<ol class="search-results results" start="1" data-total-results="16514">
```

and consist of children like

```
<li data-result-number="1">
<li data-result-number="2">
<li data-result-number="3">
<li data-result-number="4">
```

For example, here is the entire first result

```
<li data-result-number="1">
   <article class=" media-text" itemscope="">
      <aside class="flags top"></aside>
      <aside class="flags mid"></aside>
      <div>
         <h1 itemprop="headline">
            <a href="http://www.bbc.co.uk/music/artists/12eec8cf-cd35-410d-91e7-31343029ac39">Apple</a>
         </h1>
         <p class="summary short">…The BBC artist page for <em>Apple</em>. Find the best clips, programmes, news and interviews…</p>
         <p class="summary medium">…The BBC artist page for <em>Apple</em>. Find the best clips, programmes, news and interviews.…</p>
         <p class="summary long">…The BBC artist page for <em>Apple</em>. Find the best clips, programmes, news and interviews.…</p>
         <footer>
            <dl>
               <dt>Tags</dt>
               <dd><span class="signpost-site" data-site="music">Music</span><span class="signpost-section">Artists</span>
               </dd>
            </dl>
         </footer>
      </div>
      <a href="http://www.bbc.co.uk/music/artists/12eec8cf-cd35-410d-91e7-31343029ac39" class="rs_touch"></a>
      <span class="divide"></span>
   </article>
</li>
```

From this we can see that the heading, Apple, is in an `h1` tag and contains the `A` that we seek. With this info we can craft a CSS selector like, `ol.search-results > li h1 > a`, that will find the result `A` tag inside the heading. Now that we have this, we can write code like the below that dumps the headings for each of the search results.

```
String searchTerm = "apple";
driver.get("http://www.bbc.co.uk/search?q=" + searchTerm);
List<WebElement> headingLinks = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("ol.search-results > li h1 > a"));
for (WebElement headingLink : headingLinks)
{
    System.out.println(headingLink.getText());
}
```

which dumps the following

```
Apple
Apple of my Eye
Down on the Farm: Series 1: Farm Park and Apple Crisps
Cinnamon, apple and custard Danish
Apple, sultana and cinnamon swirls
The logic in Apple buying McLaren
Supercar maker McLaren denies Apple investment report
Scotch egg with apple
Cider and apple cake
Simon Mayo Drivetime: Blackberry and Apple Bake
```

At this point, if you want to click the first link, you just need to change the code to

```
String searchTerm = "apple";
driver.get("http://www.bbc.co.uk/search?q=" + searchTerm);
List<WebElement> headingLinks = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("ol.search-results > li h1 > a"));
headingLinks.get(0).click();
```

The second link would be

```
headingLinks.get(1).click();
```

... and so on...

Comment: I m testing the code . One question here . Even though for my code `
`driver.get("http://www.bbc.co.uk/search?q=");
driver.findElement(By.id("orb-search-q")).sendKeys("apple");//enter apple
driver.findElement(By.id("orb-search-button")).click(); //click submit button` 3 steps here . Sometimes ,the code stops in step 1 or step 2 . I guess the pause should be added . Then I add this `driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);` But this doesn't work .Why

Comment: You shouldn't need a pause for those steps. Why did it stop? Was there an error or ? I would avoid using implicit waits. Use explicit waits (`WebDriverWait`) when needed.

Comment: becoz sometimes it stop at the stage of visiting BBC website .Sometimes it stops at typing the keywords "apple" .Sometimes it can perform the rest of the tasks .I dun know what the problem is .

Comment: Sounds like you have a timing issue with some ajax or javascript in the background. You should build a waitr to poll until the search button is clickable.

https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/FluentWait.html